# Git - get all commits and blobs they created

Tags: git, blob, commit

Is there a git command that can output for every commit:

1. id
2. subject
3. blobs it created with they path and size (like `git ls-tree -l -r <commit>` but only for created blobs)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To get commits (all and output one line per commit):

```
git rev-list --all --pretty=oneline
```

Then split commits by space with limit of 2 and get every commit id and message

To get blobs created by commit (recurse to subdirs, show merge commits, detect renames and copies, don't show commit id on first line):

```
git diff-tree -r -c -M -C --no-commit-id <commit-sha>
```

A bit of parsing of every line and excluding some of them — and we get list of new blobs and they path for commit

Last is to get blob sizes:

```
git cat-file --batch-check < <list-of-blob-shas>
```

And another time a bit of parsing

Comment: You can make this much faster by using the `--stdin` option to `diff-tree`. For example, `git rev-list --all | git diff-tree -r --root --diff-filter=AMC --pretty=oneline --stdin`.

Comment: maxschlepzig's answer below is important: if you're trying to do something like [delete a large file from the repo history](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Maintenance-and-Data-Recovery#Removing-Objects), you need to make sure to find every commit, even if some are on unmerged branches!

Answer (score 12):

Relying on `git rev-list` is not always enough because it

> List[s] commits that are reachable by following the parent links from the
>          given commit(s) [..]

(`git help rev-list`)

Thus it does not list commits that are on another branch and it does not list commits that are not reachable by any branch (perhaps they were created because of some `rebase` and/or detached-head actions).

Similarly, `git log` just follows the parent links from the current checked out commit. Again you don't see commits referenced by other branches or which are in a dangling state.

You can really get all commits with a command like this:

```
for i in `(find .git/objects  -type f |
             sed 's@^.*objects/\(..\)/\(.\+\)$@\1\2@' ;
           git verify-pack -v .git/objects/pack/*.idx  |
             grep commit |
             cut -f1 -d' '; ) | sort -u`
  do
  git log -1 --pretty=format:'%H %P %ai %s%n'  $i
done
```

To keep it simple, the loop body prints for each commit one line containing its hash, the parent hash(es), date and subject. Note, to iterate over *all* commits you need to consider packed and not-yet packed objects.

You can print the referenced blobs (and only created ones) by calling `git diff-tree $i` (and greping for capitial `A` in the fifth column) from the loop body.

Comment: What about using `git log --all`? The docs seem to imply that will include every (reachable) commit...

Comment: @ytpete, I explicitly mention unreachable commits in my answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can get everything but size out of the box.  This one is pretty close:

```
git log --name-status
```

Comment: What does it do?

Answer (score 5):

One solution based on [tig's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1318854):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

foreach my $rev (`git rev-list --all --pretty=oneline`) {
  my $tot = 0;
  ($sha = $rev) =~ s/\s.*$//;
  foreach my $blob (`git diff-tree -r -c -M -C --no-commit-id $sha`) {
    $blob = (split /\s/, $blob)[3];
    next if $blob == "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"; # Deleted
    my $size = `echo $blob | git cat-file --batch-check`;
    $size = (split /\s/, $size)[2];
    $tot += int($size);
  }
  print "$tot $rev" if $tot > 1000000; # Show only if > 1MiB
}
```

Maybe not the best code, but should get you most of the way.

Answer (score 2):

Another useful command when searching for

```
git fsck --lost-found
```

will show dangling commits. I needed to use this to find a commit a i wiped with an ill-timed reset --hard

But don't take my word for it:

https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fsck.html

Comment: Umm could you comment the downvote - I'll remove the answer if it's erroneous or misleading!

Answer (score 0):

You can also get a list of *all* commits (including the dangling ones) with:

`git log --walk-reflogs | grep -E -o '[0-9a-f]{40}'`

Include this line in the settings for a new view in gitk (in the last input field, the command to generate additional commits) and you will get a tree that also shows the 'forgotten history' of the project.

Comment: Doesn't work for me: `git log --walk-reflogs` gives a _shorter_ list than just doing `git log`. Judging by [the man page](http://gitmanual.org/git-reflog.html), the reflog is not in any way guaranteed to be an exhaustive list of all commits or all branches...