# Git, see a list of comments of my last N commits

Tags: git, git-commit

Is there a way to see a list of comments and time of my last N commits in Git?

After looking on SO, the only relevant thing I have found is
[Git - get all commits and blobs they created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314950/git-get-all-commits-and-blobs-they-created), but it shows all commits from all users, and outputs a lot of other information.

Answer (score 329, accepted):

If you want to use the command line you can use the `--author=<your name>`

For example: to see your last 5 commits

```
git log -n 5 --author=Salvador
```

If you want a simpler one line solution:

```
git log --oneline -n 5 --author=Salvador
```

**Edited to add**

If you like the single line version, try creating an alias for `git log` like this (this is what I have for zsh)

```
alias glog="git log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit"
```

Now, I can just use:

```
glog -n 5
```

And I get a nice output such as:

[image: Terminal output]

Which is colourised, shows the name of the author and also shows the graph and you can still pass in other flags (such as --author) which lets you filter it even more.

Comment: You can save two keystrokes, e.g. `git log -5`. If you're limiting the number of commits to output within a script, you should be kind to others and use the long option, e.g. `git log --max-count=5`.

Comment: It would be nice if a newline could be appended after the last line, but I couldn't find a good way to do that.

Comment: Note: use `git show -n 5` to see the changes of the last 5 commits

Comment: Really nice. Esp if you combine it with `--after="2022-12-1` etc

Answer (score 17):

Use the `--author` and/or `--committer` filtering options with `git log`, plus the `-n` option to limit the number of commits. For example:

```
git log --author='Salvador Dali' -n 10
```

Answer (score 8):

```
git log --format="%h %B" --oneline -n 1
```

This will get you latest git log comment block with abbreviated commit id.

```
git log --format="%H %B" -n 1
```

This will get you latest git log comment block with full commit id.

You can build your own format from : [Git Pretty Format](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats)

Comment: using the --oneline will never show full commit id. Also, capital H is required to show full commit id. I suggest experimenting with the commands without the --oneline

Comment: Fixed it for the lurkers

Answer (score 5):

`git log --author="My name" -n 5` (see `man git-log` for all alternatives)

Answer (score 4):

If you are after only the last X git commit messages, the following command will give you the last 5 commit messages as strings separated by new lines:

```sh
git log -5 --oneline --format=%s | sed 's/^.*: //'
```

will output something like this:

```sh
Remove references to Node 8
Move ESLint cache file into node_modules
Update postcss packages
Add TypeScript 4.x as peerDependency to react-scripts
Create FUNDING.yml
```

Answer (score 3):

See a list of comments of last N commits

```
git log --oneline -10
```

Check out to an older commit

```
git ckeckout 3e6bb80
```

Get back to the latest commit after checking out a previous commit

```
git checkout -
```

Answer (score 2):

working like `less` with pretty format and without prompt to continue:

```
git --no-pager log --decorate=short --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' -n5
```

works beautifully

Answer (score 1):

git log --max-count=15 --pretty="format:%C(dim green) %<(9,trunc)%ar %C(bold magenta)%h %C(bold green)%<(12,trunc)%an %C(bold
yellow)%<(113,trunc)%s" --no-merges

Notice ...yellow)%<(113,trunc) the 113 is the length to trim the comments to allowing full customization without --oneline overriding your settings.

As has been said this could be aliased or as I have wrapped in a powershell function.

The following is beyond the OP but brings some value to the thread.

I know I got carried away but it is what we do.

```
    function logs() {
<#
    .SYNOPSIS 
     Shows my logs  
    .DESCRIPTION 
     Returns an abreviated list of logs meeting the filtering provided including max returned, committor by case sensitive pattern, branch, local or remote, and a 'my' shourcut to get the callers commits only
    .EXAMPLE
    PS>logs
     
    [ Basic usage gets maximum 15 logs from the origin/<current branch> ]


 origin/master logs

git log origin/master --max-count=15 --pretty="format:%C(dim green) %<(9,trunc)%ar %C(bold magenta)%h %C(bold green)%<(12,trunc)%an %C(bold yellow)%<(113,trunc)%s"

 2 days .. b6e4d0b Joe Johnston Added Posh
 2 days .. 0f1a166 Joe Johnston Updated the profile system
 4 days .. dfd3115 Joe Johnston added .net install and pinned applications. Updated git functions
 6 weeks.. 47bd9e9 Joe Johnston updated functions
 3 month.. 5148f09 Joe Johnston initial add

    .EXAMPLE
    PS>logs -l
     
    [ Usage gets maximum 15 local logs from the <current branch> ]


  logs

git log  --max-count=15 --pretty="format:%C(dim green) %<(9,trunc)%ar %C(bold magenta)%h %C(bold green)%<(12,trunc)%an %C(bold yellow)%<(113,trunc)%s"

 3 hours.. efb36e9 Joe Johnston updated profile to set-execution
 3 hours.. 4355a00 Joe Johnston Merge branch 'master' of https://github.com/xxx
 3 hours.. 84cd380 Joe Johnston updated gitfunctions - added undomerge
 2 days .. b6e4d0b Joe Johnston Added Posh
 2 days .. 0f1a166 Joe Johnston Updated the profile system
 4 days .. dfd3115 Joe Johnston added .net install and pinned applications. Updated git functions
 6 weeks.. 47bd9e9 Joe Johnston updated functions
 3 month.. 5148f09 Joe Johnston initial add

     
    .EXAMPLE
     logs 25

     [ Usage gets maximum 25 logs from the origin/<current branch> ]
    .EXAMPLE
     logs -m -c 20

     [ Usage gets maximum 20 local logs from the <current branch> commited by me]
    .EXAMPLE
     logs -b dev/iOS -c 25 -l -c "Jackson"

     [ Usage gets maximum 20 local logs from the <current branch> commited by the <pattern> Jackson]
#>
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$false,ValueFromPipeline)]
    [Alias('c')]
        [int]$Count = 15,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$false,ValueFromPipeline)]
    [Alias('b')]
        [string]$Branch = "Current",
    [parameter(Mandatory=$false,ValueFromPipeline)]
    [Alias('u')]
    [Alias('user')]
        [string]$Committer = "",
    [parameter(Mandatory=$false,ValueFromPipeline)]
    [Alias('m')]
    [Alias('me')]
    [Alias('onlyme')]
        [switch]$My = $false,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$false,ValueFromPipeline)]
    [Alias('g')]
        [switch]$Graph = $false,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$false,ValueFromPipeline)]

    [Alias('sm')]
    [Alias('merge')]
        [switch]$ShowMerges = $false,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$false,ValueFromPipeline)]

    [Alias('r')]
        [switch]$Remote = $false
    )
    $merge = '--no-merges';
    if ($ShowMerges) {
        $merge = '';
    }
    $Pretty = "--pretty=`"format:%C(dim green) %<(9,trunc)%ar %C(bold magenta)%h %C(bold green)%<(12,trunc)%an %C(bold yellow)%<(113,trunc)%s`"";
    #git config --global format.pretty $Pretty 
    if ($Branch -eq "Current") { 
        $Branch = git symbolic-ref --short HEAD; 
        write-host "************************************************";
        } else { 
        write-host "================================================";
        }

    if ($Remote -eq $true) { $Where = "origin/$Branch"; }
    if ($Graph -eq $true) { $GraphTag = "--graph"; }
    
     if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Committer) -eq $false) {
        $Who = $Committer;
        $Committer = "--committer=" + $Committer;
        write-host $Who
     }

    if ($My -eq $true) { 
        $me = git config user.name;
        $Committer = "--committer=`"$me`"";
        $Who = "**MY**";
    }

    write-host "$Who $Where logs" -foregroundcolor "Red";
    $commandOut = "git log $Where $GraphTag --max-count=$Count $Pretty $Committer $GraphTag $merge";
    write-Verbose $commandOut;
    write-host;

    git log $Where --max-count=$Count $Pretty $Committer $GraphTag $merge  
    write-host 
}
```