# How can I get the Git commits done in the last 3 months counted from the last commit on a branch?

Tags: git, git-log

I know that e.g. with

```
git shortlog -sn --since=3.months <branch>
```

I can get the commits done in the last 3 months on `<branch>` counted from *now*. But how can I make the `3.months` count from the date of the *last commit* on `<branch>` instead? Is there a syntax for this to work in a single command, or would it require multiple `git` invocations?

Answer (score 2):

Get the date of the last commit on the branch with

```
git log --format='%ai' <branch> -n1
```

- `--format='%ai'` will show only the author date. Author date is the date the commit was originally made. It is not affected by things like rebasing. If you want the commit date, use %ci.
- `-n1` says to only show the latest commit in the branch.

`date` can do date math, so use that to subtract 3 months. Then feed that to --since.

```
git log --since "$(date --date "$(git log --format='%ai' <branch> -n1) - 3 months")" <branch>
```

You will probably want to turn this into an alias.

Comment: I tried `git log --format='%ai' main -n1` didn't produce anything. what did I do wrong?

Comment: @Sentry.co Dunno. You should get something, or `fatal: ambiguous argument 'main': unknown revision or path not in the working tree` if main does not exist. Does `git log --format=fuller -n1` give anything, and does that commit have an Author Date?

Comment: @Sentry.co It's also possible something about your pager or terminal is interfering and eating the line. Try `-n5` to show 5 lines and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks. I found another one that worked https://stackoverflow.com/a/13542327/5389500 I suppose I can add the date command to that.