# Removing commits that have a size (in disk space) larger than a given value

Tags: git

After reading through:

[How to remove a too large file in a commit when my branch is ahead of master by 5 commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002557/how-to-remove-a-too-large-file-in-a-commit-when-my-branch-is-ahead-of-master-by/28959619)

https://help.github.com/en/articles/working-with-large-files

https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/

https://help.github.com/en/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository

[Show commit size in git log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40697663/show-commit-size-in-git-log)

[Git - get all commits and blobs they created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314950/git-get-all-commits-and-blobs-they-created/1318854#1318854)

I couldn't find an elegant solution of removing commits that exceed a given size (on disk). These commits do not necessarily have large files, but are large in and of themselves (have many ~200 KB dependencies).

How can such commits be removed from the repository?

Comment: [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40698537/7976758) that you linked to starts with: "*The "size" of a commit can mean different things. If you mean how much disk storage it takes up... that's very tricky to tell in Git and probably unproductive.*" In short, there is no "an elegant solution of *calculating* commit size".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a note :

`git` compresses files when it stores them in its `.git/` structure, and tries to store similar files using only their diffs ;

in that sense, it is difficult to spot "what commit uses up the most space in my `.git/` folder".

---

If you want to measure how much space the files in a commit take up when checked out :

```
git ls-tree -r -l <commitid>
```

will list the files along with their individual sizes

```
git ls-tree -r -l <commitid> | awk '{ sum += $4 } END { print sum }'
```

will print the total size of these files.

---

You can put the above shortcut in a script and see what commits take up more than `xx` bytes, the next thing is : can you get rid of said commits ?

You may tell git to delete the end of a branch :

```
If all 'B's mark 'big commits' :

               +-- create a new branch here
               v
*--*--*--*--*--*--B--B--B--B <- branchA
    \              \
     \              \-B--B <- branchB
      \
       *--*--*--* <- branchC
              \
               \--B <- branchD
```

In the above diagram, you can tell git to forget `branchA`,  `branchB` and `branchD` (and possibly create a new reference to keep the first "no so big" commits),

but when a commit appears in the middle of a branch :

```
*--*--B--B--*--* <- branchE
```

your notion of "delete the two Bs" depends heavily on what is stored in your `git` repo and how you can remove these commits from a branch's history.

The general advice is : do not delete commits.

Comment: Thanks. In my case "B" commits are interleaved with normal sized commits (and are not located at the end of the branch (I added a filter in .gitignore for dependencies (with a few exceptions)). I agree that commits shouldn't be (generally) deleted, but in this case they pollute the repo (and are not critical to the project).

Comment: @Sebi : ok. Do you see how to edit the history of your repo ?

Comment: Yes. I can remove the commits individually (I'll write a bash script for this).